# How to let Nextcloud user login in django with single sign similar to "Login with Github" in SO?

Tags: django, oauth, ldap, single-sign-on, nextcloud

I have a Nextcloud instance where all potential users have an account.

I would like to set up an [Open Source Doodle (Bitpoll)](https://github.com/fsinfuhh/Bitpoll) that is django based, as I don't like the nextcloud poll app.

For security reasons I would like to limit the Doodle app to users of my nextcloud. Also I don't want them to enter a password using the doodle app (so single sign on is required).
I imagine a similar user user flow as the `Login in with Github` button that can be used to also create user accounts.

The doodle app supports LDAP, so does nextcloud.

There are django modules for OAuth as well as for the nextcloud.

I have no LDAP experience at all and only very little OAuth experience.

**With which Nextcloud Settings / Apps and which Django Apps (and an idea of the settings) can I realize the explained scenario?**

To be more precise:

1. Do I need to use LDAP at all? Or can I configure OAuth in a way that all users that come from `nextcloud.mydomain.org` generate a new account in the app?
2. What are the correct OAuth terms for my nextcloud istance and for the doodle app in this scenario? Is nextcloud a OAuth Server and doodle an OAuth Client?
3. What django modules could I use?
4. Do I confuse OAuth with OpenID in this scenario?

Comment: If you have a better idea for the title, especially the "user master", please tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Do I need to use LDAP at all? Or can I configure OAuth in a way that all users that  come from nextcloud.mydomain.org generate a new account in the app?

No. LDAP is a user directory itself. If you don't have one, just go on, because if you would like to use LDAP at all, you need to migrate NCs user data to LDAP (and run an LDAP Server, what I would totally not recomment).

#### What are the correct OAuth terms for my nextcloud istance and for the doodle app in this scenario? Is nextcloud a OAuth Server and doodle an OAuth Client?

Absolutely! Nextcloud is the OAuth Provider or OAuth Server, while everything else is a client. Lucky you: Nextcloud is an OAuth2 Provider by default.

#### What django modules could I use?

The [authlib](https://docs.authlib.org/en/stable/client/django.html) provides an OAuth Module. Adding an OAuth Client is done on nextcloud's admin security page. See [the NC docs](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/stable/admin_manual/configuration_server/oauth2.html) for more information.

Authlib parameters should be like:

```py
AUTHLIB_OAUTH_CLIENTS = {
    'twitter': {
        'client_id': 'pMBV0rbvMg2mhw', # "Client Identifier" in Nextcloud
        'client_secret': 'Twitter Consumer Secret', # "Secret" in Nextcloud
        'request_token_url': 'https://YOUR_NC_URL/index.php/apps/oauth2/api/v1/token',
        'request_token_params': None,
        'access_token_url': 'https://YOUR_NC_URL/index.php/apps/oauth2/api/v1/token',
        'access_token_params': None,
        'refresh_token_url': None,
        'authorize_url': 'https://YOUR_NC_URL/index.php/apps/oauth2/authorize',
        'api_base_url': None, # have never seen this option...
        'client_kwargs': None
    }
}
```

*Disclaimer:* I have never used django (nor python), but I use some OAuth clients with NC what works very well. The only thing is, that I never had to input an `api_base_url`, so I set it to `None` above, because docs state that `[e]very key value pair can be omit`.

#### Do I confuse OAuth with OpenID in this scenario?

No, not really. OAuth is exactly made for what you want, and used by *many* NC Apps, while OpenID sits on top of OAuth (and JWT).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will need some time to verify and test but looks promising for receiving the bounty.

Comment: It's not about the bounty. It's about the fun and my love for nextcloud and the open source community (and about well-phrased questions!) ;) - But will surely not reject it.